# How to eliminate the errors around edge boundaries after cutting out the Image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation, edge-detection, smoothing

I'm making an image processing project which has a 6-step algorithm and I'm stuck in one of these.

First off all, the platform I using is MATLAB, so if you can supply some samples it would be great. But if you don't want to write code samples, please just give me some hints, techniques or etc.

Let me explain my problem. I've segmented a .jpg image and cut out some areas of it. Then I save the result as .png using a mask. The result is like that (The black part is actually transparent, I made it black to see better the problem);

[image]

As you may see in the picture, there is some irrelevant areas. I need to get rid of these irrelevant areas. Because I want the foreground as much as smooth. At the first sight, I applied Gaussian blur to the mask and save the image as .png, again. But the result isn't satisfying as you can imagine. I suppose this situation is needed more solid solution than I have tried.

Edit1: I used spectral matting. But it doesn't help. The best result that I can receive is like that;

[image]

As you can see there is some problems on the face and lots of problems on the bottom side of the picture. I guess I need kind of edge fixer or edge smoother for the first image above and it should be faster than matting.

Any MATLAB code samples, technique and approach would be great. If you need further explanation, feel free to ask.

Comment: Please explain how the segmentation is performed. It seems you are segmenting using absolute color values, ignoring the gradient.

Comment: Yes, you are partly right. It is based on color similarity of a node. I'm minimizing the Gibbs energy. As you may have known, Boykov and Jolly's (2001) Graph cut algorithms works very well. But in the finalized result, there are just a few little problems as you can see.

Comment: @Erdi are you using 4-connected grid graph or 8-connect? You might consider higher degree of connectivity as suggested by http://www.cs.cornell.edu/People/vnk/papers/BK-ICCV03.pdf or http://pub.ist.ac.at/~vnk/papers/KB-ICCV05.pdf

Comment: @Shai I'm using 4-connected graph. At the first article you added, there are some sample usage of 8-n and 26-n. The results are very impressive. It really is. I think this will solve my edge smoothing part properly. I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 5):

You do not want just to "Gauss-blur" the result, you want soft segmentation a.k.a [matting](http://www.computervisiononline.com/books/computer-vision/image-matting). As a first stop for image matting I would recommend Levine Rav-Acha and Lischinski [*Spectral Matting*](http://www.vision.huji.ac.il/SpectralMatting/). You'll find some Matlab code there (I used it in the past - very impressive results).

Comment: I have integrated Spectral Matting code to my project but clearly the results are not so well. First of all, it is really slow. (averagely 6 min for a 1000x500 image file). Moreover, there is some problems with accuracy of foreground. Most of the times, it includes other irrelevant parts to the result. As you can understand this doesn't help to situation. Is there something else to apply the image above. I don't know, maybe kind of edge fixer, edge smoother ?

Comment: @Erdiİzgi you can try the matting algorithm proposed in the [GrabCut](http://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/cvl/2012/grabcut-siggraph04.pdf) paper in section 4.